# Spring Boot test Kafka

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE, and I have this problem:

Have you a solution please ?

```
[Thread-2] ERROR o.a.k.t.TestUtils - Error deleting C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-255644115154741962
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-255644115154741962\version-2\log.1: 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.visitFile(Utils.java:734)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.visitFile(Utils.java:723)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:723)
    at org.apache.kafka.test.TestUtils$1.run(TestUtils.java:184)
```

This is my test, i use a windows 10 like OS,
This is my test,

```
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.junit.Test;

import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
import kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper;

public class BaseTest {

private static final String ZKHOST = "127.0.0.1";

@Test
public void producerTest(){

    // setup Zookeeper
    EmbeddedZookeeper zkServer = new EmbeddedZookeeper();
    String zkConnect = ZKHOST + ":" + zkServer.port();
    ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(zkConnect, 30000, 30000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
    ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply(zkClient, false);

    zkClient.close();
    zkServer.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show your test case.

Comment: The post is updated,